# Problem regarding moderation of my question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked a question recently on Chemistry stackexchange after someone from the Physics side of the fence recommend [I ask it here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/82352/delocalised-electrons-electric-field), which seemed fair enough. My understanding of the scope of Chemistry is relating to interactions and changes involving molecules / atoms / electron orbitals, so while my question may sit on the fence, I and a commenter think that it can belong here as electrons and their repulsions are important for modelling molecules.

My question was closed, not migrated, and for the reason of "being unclear". Unless I'm asking a  question that is formulated so badly that it makes no sense [possible, but no-one has communicated that] how is that justified?

Answer (score 10):

I have left you a comment on your question:

> While I do not understand the question itself, I have a strong feeling, that if I understood it, I would say it is on topic here. However, I have troubles with 'delocalised with respect to position' - Is there any other delocalisation? Then I don't quite get what 'some space' is. All in all, this question reads quite vague and might be missing some context of what problem you are actually facing - or maybe I am just not educated enough in this field to get what you mean. In any case, the question could use some more clarity.

It might be just me, and usually when these kinds of questions are asked, someone else will provide enough context so that I'll eventually get it. So far I simply don't understand what you really want to know.
Apparently I am not the only one as your question is on hold for not being clear enough, not for being off topic. That's something that can easily be fixed. Add some more context, some more explanations for people not working in the field so that the general audience also has a chance to understand it.

This kind of moderation is by far superior to just down-voting and letting your question meander around for a while. It (as you did) opens up other ways of communication and clarification.
As I am not one of the people who voted for your question to be put on hold, I cannot attest to their issues with it. Once you edit your question, it will be put into review and I guess it has a good chance of being reopened.
These are all democratic processes, and unless some ugly ping-pong effect happens, I see no need to actually interfere with it.

Comment: Actually, I think I understand what OP is trying to ask; OP wants to find an expression for the [electric field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_field) $\vec{E}(\vec{r})$ generated by a charge density $\rho(\vec{r})$, e.g. that of an electron in a given orbital. The question is whether OP should use a superposition of electric fields arising from an infinite number of point charges, or whether OP should find the expectation value of the position of the electron, and treat the electron as being a point charge of $-e$.

Comment: @ortho now that is something I can grasp

Comment: Well, all's well that ends well... https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/356473

Answer (score 5):

Just because it is on topic for Physics doesn't automatically make it off topic for Chemistry.

It's probably on topic for Chemistry as well, but I believe that you would get a better response on Physics. And it seems that I am not the only person who thinks so, which is why I asked you: *who* told you to ask it here? I find it a little odd that somebody from Physics would tell you that it is not welcome there. If it was just some random 101-rep guy, I would have simply migrated it over. But if it was - for example -  a moderator there, or a long-time user, there's no point in me doing that, because it would presumably just get closed again. It would also be rather disrespectful of me to go against their express wishes.

But at the end of the day, it is your choice where you want to ask your question. All we can do is try to help you get the best chance of having it answered. If you want it migrated to Physics, simply flag for migration, and one of us can do the job. If you want it here - well, it seems that some people don't understand what you are asking - so maybe add some explanation and it can get reopened.

Comment: I don't really want to specifically name anyone as that seems to me like blaming, but it was the recommendation of someone in a Physics chatroom after I asked him the question

Comment: OK, I found the conversation. My 2 cents is that you're better off on Phys, and I wouldn't have qualms migrating it. But considering that you've actually asked it on Phys already, your option now is to either: (1) delete the Phys question, edit the Chem question and get it reopened (which is quite likely); or (2) delete the Chem question and hopefully get an answer on Phys.

Comment: By the way - if you want to pursue option (1), and if I am understanding your question correctly (see my comment on Martin's answer) - I don't mind editing it for you. Let me know.

Comment: I already got a good answer from PhysSE so I'll delete my ChemSE question. Thanks for the help

Comment: What do I do with the meta post? Delete it too?

Comment: I can delete it for you, if you'd like (I think the system prevents you from deleting it yourself).

Comment: I don't mind, it just depends on whether this question actually has anything of merit to besides just me trying to get an answer. It probably doesn't question moderation too generally, so feel free to delete it